# Foreach inside function

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function dp(){

        $this->load->library('heart');



        $times = 35;

        $i = 0; while ($i<$times){
        $this->heart->test();

        //10 newest
        $query = $this->db->get('test', 10, 20);


            //set variables from query
        foreach ($query->result() as $getrow)
        {
         $data1 = $getrow->data1;
         $data2 = $getrow->data2;
        }
        //for each data1; do go();
        foreach ($data1 as $id){
            $this->heart->go($id,$data2);
            }

        //increment $i  
        $i++;   
        }

        }
```

Hey guys, here is my code. I am trying to get the most newest entries from the database, then setting them as variables. For each variable, I am trying to call a function to it passing $id (data1) and $data2. Will data2 be passed or do I need to do something like $data1 as $id && $data2 as $id2. I need to pass over $data1 and $data2 to go() which should be different everytime.

The problem here is I keep getting 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' whenever I try to run the code. Anyone know what the issue is here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you actually want to be creating arrays of `$data1` and `$data2`.

Currently you are overwriting the values in each of those variable each time through the first foreach loop.

```
$data1 = array();
$data2 = array();
//set variables from query
foreach ($query->result() as $getrow)
{
    $data1[] = $getrow->data1;
    $data2[] = $getrow->data2;
}
//for each data1; do go();
foreach ($data1 as $key => $id){
    $this->heart->go($id,$data2[$key]);
}
```

Alternatively you could use data1 and data2 as the key/value pair of the array

```
$data = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $getrow)
{
    $data[$getrow->data1] = $getrow->data2;
}
//for each data1; do go();
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    $this->heart->go($key, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all with a single foreach loop without building unnecessary data arrays:

```
foreach($query->result() as $getrow) {
   $this->heart->go($getrow->data1, $getrow->data2);
}
```